# How to make the files appear using the correct while loop?

Tags: c

In this code, when I use `while() loop with {....}`, the result shows me only one directory name. Although there are many files and directories. But when I use `while()` loop without `{...}`, the result shows me all the directories and files present in the given path. How to show all the directories and file using `{....}` or is there another way?

```
int watch(char *dirname){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entity;
    char path[500] = {0};

    dir = opendir(dirname);
    if(dir != NULL){
        while(entity = readdir(dir)){
            puts(entity->d_name);
            closedir(dir);
        }
    }
    else
        perror("Couldn't open the directory");
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample input to demonstrate your problem. Ideally avoid any input, e.g. by using hard-coded intialised variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't about whether or not you use `{}`, but rather what is inside those `{}`. In this case, you call `closedir()` inside the while loop and so the next iteration fails. If you instead move `closedir()` outside the braces, you will get the same behavior as when you don't use the braces at all:

```
int watch(char *dirname){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entity;
    char path[500] = {0};

    dir = opendir(dirname);
    if(dir != NULL){
        while(entity = readdir(dir)){
            puts(entity->d_name);
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    else
        perror("Couldn't open the directory");
}
```

Note this is identical to the version of code that doesn't have `{}` in it. I suggest you add `printf()` statements to your original code to understand why it works the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

By chance you have found a fix for the mistake in your code.
With the `{}` you always execute the `closedir()` in EACH iteration, but obviously you only want to close your access to the directory after you are completly done with it - i.e. AFTER the whole loop.
And as you are probably aware, C uses `{}` to determine what is inside a block, i.e. in this case a looped set of statements. Indentation is irrelevant.

So

```
while(entity = readdir(dir))
    puts(entity->d_name);
    closedir(dir);
```

inspite of appearance, does the correct thing, to only close after the whole loop, not each iteration.

```
while(entity = readdir(dir))
{
    puts(entity->d_name);
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Does the incorrect thing, to close the directory always - or actually after the first iteration, which makes all others fail.

If you insist on using the `{}` (you probably have more statements in the loop which you need iterated, only removed for making a MRE), then you have to keep only the statements inside the `{}` which you want in all iterations and move the statement(s) outside which you want only once and after the whole loop.

```
while(entity = readdir(dir))
{
    puts(entity->d_name);
}
closedir(dir);
```